# How to give values up to 24 in kendo timepicker?

Tags: php, kendo-ui

I want to specify values from 1 to 24 without giving `AM` or `PM` format, so that I can avoid extra validations. My demo code is,

```
$startTime = new \Kendo\UI\TimePicker('StartTime');
          $startTime->value($stime)
           ->format('hh:mm')
        ->attr('name','data[Branch][StartTime]');
        echo $startTime->render();
```

So please specify proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line `->format('hh:mm')` by the following code

`->format('HH:mm')`

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Yes, it is giving me values up to 24 but one value appearing 2 times

Comment: Yes dude it will, bcz HH:mm is written,
if you want to single time just write H:m

Comment: ya i want HH:mm format but i had written HH:MM that's why it was appearing two times,means 12:00, 12:00....  But now corrected my mistake... Thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

Use this format: `format('HH:mm')`